# Problem useEffect and react router in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I set useEffect for only the first time running the `console.log("hello");`. But when I click the Home link, the useEffect run many times. Why is that? How do I fix it?

https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-wildflower-updeh?file=/src/Home.js:95-298

```
const Home = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("hello");
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>History</h1>
      <Link to="/">Home</Link>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: what do you mean it runs many times? It only logs after the rendering the component at the moment

Comment: Your component is remounted after the redirect

Comment: When I click the Home many times, The logs print many times

Comment: the '/' route routes back again to home page, so it will run on every render, pretty much expected.

Answer (score 3):

The `useEffect` is running every time despite the `[]` argument because the component itself is mounting/unmounting every time. Why? Because `react-router` is not properly configured, so it's essentially refreshing the page every time, since `react-router` isn't there to intercept it. That's likely not what you want — to resolve, you can use `history.push()` for navigation, but better would be to set up the [Router instance](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/basic) itself.